# Searching File and Returning 2 Strings

Tags: python, search, python-requests

I am wanting to search through this for "name" and return the name, which I already have the code for. However, I need to return the "1" or "4" along with it so I end up with:

1 - corner light

I can then send a HTTP PUT to the correct device with the rest of my program. I can't find anything on how to go about this, any help is appreciated.

```
 names = [js[index]["name"] for index in js]
 print (names)     
{
"1": {
    "state": {
        "on": true,
        "bri": 114,
        "alert": "none",
        "reachable": true
    },
    "type": "Dimmable light",
    "name": "corner light",
},
"4": {
    "state": {
        "on": true,
        "bri": 180,
        "alert": "none",
        "reachable": true
    },
    "type": "Dimmable light",
    "name": "Back light",
},
"5": {
    "state": {
        "on": true,
        "bri": 228,
        "alert": "none",
        "reachable": true
    },
    "type": "Dimmable light",
    "name": "Best Bulb",
},
"7": {
    "state": {
        "on": false,
        "bri": 254,
        "alert": "none",
        "reachable": false
    },
    "type": "Dimmable light",
    "name": "our bulb",
},
```

Comment: do you mean `[ (index, js[index]["name"]) for index in js ]` ?

Comment: What's in `js` variable?

Comment: @martineau I assume `js` is this `json` in the body of the post, but @furas solution looks correct

Answer (score 0):

Just concatenate the index and the separator in your statement:

```
names = [index + " - " + js[index]["name"] for index in js]
```

This gives output

```
['1 - corner light', '5 - Best Bulb', '4 - Back light', '7 - our bulb']
```

BTW, you'll need to capitalize the Boolean values (True & False) to keep Python happy.